Can Windows 10+ set a default fallback audio device?
If you have 3 speakers - internal, headphones and external - and you choose the headphones to be the default one, can you make it so if the headphones disconnect then the external ones will take over as the new default instead of the internal mic?
Likewise if you have 3 microphones - internal, headphones and webcam - and you choose the headphones to be the default one, can you make it so if the headphones disconnect then the webcam will take over as the new default instead of the internal mic?
Sort of like a secondary default.
